# App Clip Local Experience shows "No usable data found" after scan

Tags: ios, apple-appclips

I'm following the instructions to create and [test a Local Experience for an App Clip](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/app_clips/testing_the_launch_experience_of_your_app_clip).

After I set it up and scan the code, I see

> APP CLIP CODE
>
> No usable data found

I made sure to:

- Installed the full app and App Clip to the test device.
- Added the associated domain to the full app (e.g. `applinks:com.apple.wwdc`
- Added the associated domain to the App Clip (e.g. `appclips:com.apple.wwdc`)
- Updated the Apple App Site Association file to reference the same app id (e.g. `"appIDs": [ "ABCD1234.com.apple.wwdc" ]`) and app clip id (e.g. `"apps": ["ABCD1234.com.apple.wwdc.Clip"]`)
- Created the Local Experience via Settings

  - Entered the Bundle ID for the App Clip (e.g. `ABCD1234.com.apple.wwdc.Clip`)

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if you enter the bundle ID incorrectly.

For example, when you're creating an [Apple App Site Association](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html) file or [associating the App Clip with your website](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/app_clips/associating_your_app_clip_with_your_website), you always need to enter an App ID (`ABCD1234.com.apple.wwdc.Clip`).

However, the [documentation for testing a local experience states](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/app_clips/testing_the_launch_experience_of_your_app_clip):

> Enter the bundle ID of your App Clip

So the Bundle ID field in the Local Experience screen should *not* contain the Application Identifier Prefix:

```
com.apple.wwdc.Clip
```

See the [comprehensive list of Apple identifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74947114/35690) for more info.

Comment: Did I waste 4 hours banging my head why my app clip wasn't triggering? Yes I did.
Thank you for this, I have entered the full App ID as well.

Answer (score 0):

I got mine working at the beginning but then it stop working.
Go to settings -> App Clips, remove your app clip and run your project again.